# Query JSON nested array and expand to multiple rows in Postgres table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This is the JSON object I'm querying:

```
const data =
{"fruit":["apple"],"vegetables":["carrot","turnip"],"dairy":["milk","cheese"]}'
```

Here's what I want to return in my postgres table:

```
  category   | item
--------------------
  fruit      |  apple 
  vegetables |  carrot
  vegetables |  apple 
  dairy      |  milk
  dairy      |  cheese
```

This is what I've managed to do so far:

```
SELECT key as category, value as item
FROM json_each_text('${data}')
```

```
  category   | item
--------------------
  fruit      |  ["apple"] 
  vegetables |  ["carrot", "turnip"]
  dairy      |  ["milk", "cheese"]
```

Does anybody know how to unnest/expand the values in the item column onto new rows? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close.

Just extract the items from the json arrays using [`json_array_elements_text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT key as category, json_array_elements_text(value::json) as item
FROM json_each_text('{"fruit":["apple"],"vegetables":["carrot","turnip"],"dairy":["milk","cheese"]}'::json);
  category  |  item  
------------+--------
 fruit      | apple
 vegetables | carrot
 vegetables | turnip
 dairy      | milk
 dairy      | cheese
(5 Zeilen)
```

In case you ever face this issue with other types of arrays, consider using [`UNNEST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['foo','bar']);
 unnest 
--------
 foo
 bar
(2 Zeilen)

SELECT UNNEST('{"foo","bar"}'::TEXT[]);
 unnest 
--------
 foo
 bar
(2 Zeilen)
```